# iOS status bar overlap pwa elements

Tags: ios, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, fullscreen

I have the following problem on a pwa. I tried to fix the "fullscreen problem" on iOS, but after I added

padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);

on the container my app looks like this:
[image]

I have some containers with "position: fixed", but I can't change that. Any suggestions on how I could fix this?